# How can I make this symbol in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, symbols

I need to redraw this symbol for a client that has it as a JPG logo but doesn't have the vectorized file. How can I do this in illustrator?

[image]

Comment: We can help you with any difficulties you have during the process, but please at least show us that you tried something, or at least did some research on how to do it. We're not here to do work for free.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you haven't shown what you've tried, where you need help etc. Please include that information.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do can be accomplished with the Transform Each command (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) or the Rotate Tool (<kbd>R</kbd>).

To Transform Each:

1. Select your first object with the selection tool (<kbd>V</kbd>)
2. Select Transform Each (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
3. Set a value for the angle, eg. 10°
4. Play around with the 'Move' values and the anchor origin until your copies line up nicely the way you want them to.
5. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat your transformation

[image]

You can also adjust the scaling of each new copy with this command.

OR

Use the Rotate Tool:

1. Select the Rotate tool <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Set the "Origin Point"; This determines where all your copies will rotate around
3. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging to create a copy
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to repeat your transformation

[image]

---

You'll need to tweak the spaces, the number of copies and scale of the object each time you transform it but this should get you started in the right direction.